# Sum up column B based on colum C values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, macros, sumifs

I have a quick question: I try to sum up in a table of 4 columns column number 2 if the value in column number 1 AND 3 matches. I found a sample code here on stack overflow, but it counts currently based on column 1. I'm new to VBA and don't know what to change or how to adjust the code to base my calculations on column 1 and 3. Here is the sample code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testFunction()
   Dim rng As Excel.Range
   Dim arrProducts() As String
   Dim i As Long

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A9")

arrProducts = getSumOfCountArray(rng)

Sheet2.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Product", "Sum of Count")

' go through array and output to Sheet2
For i = 0 To UBound(arrProducts, 2)
    Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, "A").Value = arrProducts(0, i)
    Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = arrProducts(1, i)
Next

End Sub

' Pass in the range of the products
Function getSumOfCountArray(ByRef rngProduct As Excel.Range) As String()
Dim arrProducts() As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim index As Long

ReDim arrProducts(1, 0)

For j = 1 To rngProduct.Rows.Count
    index = getProductIndex(arrProducts, rngProduct.Cells(j, 1).Value)
    If (index = -1) Then
        ' create value in array
        ReDim Preserve arrProducts(1, i)
        arrProducts(0, i) = rngProduct.Cells(j, 1).Value ' product name
        arrProducts(1, i) = rngProduct.Cells(j, 2).Value ' count value
        i = i + 1
    Else
        ' value found, add to id
        arrProducts(1, index) = arrProducts(1, index) + rngProduct.Cells(j, 2).Value
    End If
Next

getSumOfCountArray = arrProducts
End Function

Function getProductIndex(ByRef arrProducts() As String, ByRef strSearch As String) As Long
' returns the index of the array if found
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(arrProducts, 2)
    If (arrProducts(0, i) = strSearch) Then
        getProductIndex = i
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

' not found
getProductIndex = -1
End Function
```

[Sum Column B based on Column A using Excel VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112604/sum-column-b-based-on-column-a-using-excel-vba-macro/10113936#10113936?newreg=dc98a031ed9a4626a22e955954035ddb)

Could you please advise me how I can solve this problem. Below you can find a sample picture of my small table. The quantity of the yellow part, for instance, shall be summed up and the second row shall be deleted.

[Sample Table - Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4aXB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you said "*I try to sum up in a table of 4 columns column number 2*" but from your "Sample Table - Picture" I'd understand you want to sum up column number 4

**edited** after OP variation of data range

Assuming what above you could try the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
On Error GoTo 0

With ActiveSheet '<== set here the actual sheet reference needed
'    With .Range("A:D").Resize(.cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row) '<== here adjust "A:D" to whatever colums range you need
    With .Range("A51:D" & .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row) '<== here adjust "A:D" to whatever colums range you need
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C2, C1,RC1,C3, RC3)" '1st "helper column is the 1st column at the right of data columns (since ".Offset(, .Columns.Count)")
            .Columns(2).Value = .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).Value 'reference to 1st "helper" column (since ".Offset(, .Columns.Count)")

            .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=concatenate(RC1,RC3)"

            With .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1) '2nd "helper" column is the 2nd column at the right of data columns (since ".Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1)"
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(countIF(R1C[-1]:RC[-1],RC[-1])=countif(C[-1],RC[-1]),1,"""")" 'reference to 1st "helper" column (with all those "C[-1]")
                .Value = .Value
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                .Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2).ClearContents ' reference to both "helper" columns: ".Offset(, -1)" reference the 1st since it shifts one column to the left from the one referenced in the preceeding "With.." statement (which is the 2nd column at thre right of data columns) and ".Resize(, 2)" enlarges to encose the adjacent column to the right
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

it makes use of two "helper" columns, which I assumed could be the two adjacent to the last data columns (i.e.: if data columns are "A:D" then helper columns are "E:F")

should you need to use different "helper" columns then see comments about how they are located and change code accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much @user3598756 .... Yeah, I meant the column with the quantity to sum up based on the delivery number and product code (if those two match, then sum up) .... I will try this out thank you ... In column E is (as the next step) another calculation will take place .... So do you think the helper columns will disturb?

Comment: _In column E is (as the next step) another calculation will take place .... So do you think the helper columns will disturb?_  No, it won't disturb, since "E" and" F" "helper" columns are needed only during my "main" code run. But I'll point out once more that "main" will erase everything in those two columns, so if you have data in columns "E" and "F" before the run of the "sum-up" macro that you want to keep, then you must choose two different helper columns. BTW if you found my answer useful you may want to up-vote it. If it fulfilled your request please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: thank you. I will try it out right now. Just a last question, which line does the calculation itself? The quantities are indeed in column B (2). The picture I've attached was from the old file. Sorry for that.

Comment: the "calculation" line is `.Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C4, C1,RC1,C3, RC3)" `. Specifically: `C4` is pointing at the column 4 (D) to be summed up; all `C1` occurrences are pointing at column 1 (A)  to check for "Product Code" matches and all `C3` occurrences are pointing at column 3 (C)  to check for "Delivery Number" matches. -> change `C4` to `C2`

Comment: I think I am almost there. A small thing is not working unfortunately. If my range is from A51:D, can't I write `With .Range("A51:D" & lastrow).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`, whereas the lastrow refers like `lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count)`, "A").End(xlUp).Row'.

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count), "A").End(xlUp).Row` is not a valid syntax: there's a `)` too much. see edited answer

Comment: Hi user3598756, it worked perfectly. With a database of about 30'000 lines it takes time (about 5-6 min) but it does its purpose. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. If I fulfilled your question then please mark my answer as accepted. thank you